# I need to add log4j file to continue work after the existing one reached maximum limit of size

Tags: java, log4j

I need to make a logger file after that file reached maximum size like 2 MB and continue to work normally.

My log4j.properties

```
   # Root logger option
   log4j.rootLogger=OFF

   #log4j.logger.com.s.s=ALL, file, stdout
   log4j.logger.com.ist=ALL, file, stdout
   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=C:c.log
   log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM- 
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%x]=>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] [%c.%M] - %m%n

    # Direct log messages to stdout
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%x]=>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] [%c.%M] - %m%n
```

Comment: @Deep after I add this line
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
when the file reached it will create another file in the same path ?

Comment: Yes it will rename the old file and will create a new file

Answer (score 1):

Following this [example](http://2min2code.com/articles/log4j_intro/rolling_file_on_size_prop):

```
log4j.appender.loggerId.MaxFileSize=2MB
```